# Is there a way to prevent a specific .exe from opening files from a specific folder in Win10?

Tags: windows, file-management

We run multiple versions of a CAD program (Solidworks) on our computers (necessary for client work). Files created in newer versions of the program can't be opened in older versions. This also means if you open files created in an older version in a newer version and then save them, they can't be re-opened in the old version.

Files are opened in the normal ways - Open dialog box, drag & drop or double-click from Windows Explorer. To date, we have just relied on users being careful, and on having backups of our data (files are stored on a NAS).

We would like to prevent users from opening files from specific folders for a given executable (each version has it's own .exe) - is this possible in Windows 10?

Comment: No; You would have to revoke permissions to the file entirely to do what you want. Seems like you should create version specific copies of the file.

Comment: Natively with Windows, you can secure folders with User Permissions. So then put files you do not want opened in secure folders

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to do that, all of them should be applied:

1. create a user which opens first exe and older files
2. create a user which opens second exe and newer files
3. apply permissions to exe files and corresponding older/newer files for specific users

You can do that in-Windows for NTFS or by a simple solution in Linux ext4 file system - by groups (to which the users belong). All of that will be made depending on the file system.

You may want also to revoke (deny) access when the files/exec's don't match each other.

**EDIT:**

After comments I add:

1. create group for old exe
2. create group for new exe
3. create group for old files
4. create group for new files
5. add users to groups
6. add permissions to files/folders for specific groups

So it will be group old_exe for old exe, old_files for old files and then add each user to the groups you want him to belong to.

Surely you can make it more atomic if you need to distinguish between new_files of kind A and B.

About NAS: it should have groups and users and with these you should be able to add corresponding permissions.

Comment: The above answer should work fine for @Kieran Choy

Comment: *I am not sure I agree that any of these solutions would prevent a specific version of their CAD software from opening a specific file.*  While changing the permissions on the legacy files would protect them from being modified, they could not be opened and modified, which I presume is why they are being opened in the first place. Using a special user seems complicated when the current system the author has implemented can't be follwed.

Comment: @pbies - this is an interesting approach if it can work. Ideally users wouldn't need to log in to different Windows accounts, but it may be the only option. 


_"You may want also to revoke (deny) access when the files/exec's don't match each other."_


Do you know the specifics of how to achieve either of the above in Windows 10, with files stored on a NAS? Or point me to a guide? I have looked but have only found references to stopping Windows Defender from scanning files or similar unhelpful guides.

Comment: @pbies - On re-reading I believe you are suggesting applying User permissions to the program and folders, without requiring the user to sign in/out of accounts. 

I will have a crack at this and report back.

Comment: @KieranChoy as you grant permissions on files and folders using Properties for the file/folder (right mouse click on it) where you can find the permissions (maybe "Advanced"), the same way you deny access for users/groups. Deny is more powerful than grant access. And yes, I am talking about artificial users used only to grant/deny permissions. You have few elements here: users, groups, file/folder permissions to grant and deny. But create separate group for old/new version of exe.

Comment: Still I don't know your NAS - is it Windows NTFS formatted, or is it Linux with ext4? Or maybe sth else? Eventually you would need to change file system on this NAS (MAKING BACKUP FIRST!!!).